# join files inside every folder using batch command

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have 10-20 directories with a number of files inside in each folder. 
I want to join in a single file every pack of files inside each folder so if I have 20 folders with 2300 files I want 20 joined files.

Example

```
INPUT

folder1 - 500 files
folder2 - 340 files
folder3 - 5 files

OUTPUT REQUEST
folder1.txt (500 joined files)
folder2.txt (340 joined files)
folder3.txt (5 joined files)
```

But I have many folders so I try to find a **.bat** command to create automatically this operations.

VIDEO: [what i want](http://peterlongx.altervista.org/Flash/Richieste/join_files_in_a_single_file_for_each_folder.htm)

Comment: to do the same thing to several items, `for /?` usually is the command to use.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: `for /D %%a in (*) do copy %%a %%a.txt`

Comment: Aacini your command is great, answer me so I can check your answer. UTF-8 encoding is default, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each of your files is text file with a newline terminator at the end of each final line, then you can use the following:

```
for %%F in ("folder1" "folder2" "folder3") do >"%%F.txt" type "%%~F\*"
```

The name of each file will be output to the screen via stderr.

If you want to hide the file names:

```
for %%F in ("folder1" "folder2" "folder3") do >"%%F.txt" 2>nul type "%%~F\*"
```

If you want the file names to be included in the text file output:

```
for %%F in ("folder1" "folder2" "folder3") do >"%%F.txt" 2>&1 type "%%~F\*"
```

IF you want to process all folders within your current directory, then change the FOR command for any of the commands listed above to look like:

```
for /D %%F in (*) do ...
```

Comment: thanks for tip, but if I have different encodings for txt files (UTF-8 and Windows 1251) might I have problems to display some characters on editor like notepad ++?

Comment: @PeterLong - That is a tricky question to answer. It depends on what characters you run across. I believe cmd commands like TYPE only understand ANSI and UTF-16. The TYPE command will attempt to convert UTF-16 into ANSI, but it can only support characters that map to your current code page.. Certainly all single byte UTF-8 characters will work, but muti-byte values will not get converted properly. Your ANSI files will all work fine as long as they all use the same code page (like Windows 1251).